# Lagom withPathParamSerializer

Tags: lagom

I've seen the following code:

```
@Override
default Descriptor descriptor() {
    // TODO: add authentication? I don't think searching needs authentication... Hmmm...
    return named("search").withCalls(
            Service.restCall(Method.GET, "/search?pageNo&pageSize", this::search)
    ).withPathParamSerializer(
            UUID.class, PathParamSerializers.optional("UUID", UUID::fromString, UUID::toString)
    );
}
```

After checking the documentation, it isn't exactly clear for me what `withPathParamSerializer`is doing.
It is clear to me that you can have both optional and required.
But what is it for? This descriptor exposes a GET request, I don't see what the UUID serializer is for.

Comment: As the author of the quoted code (https://github.com/lagom/online-auction-java/blob/master/search-api/src/main/java/com/example/auction/search/api/SearchService.java) I can tell you this code is wrong. In this case `withPathParamSerializer` is not necessary.  See https://github.com/lagom/online-auction-java/blob/master/bidding-api/src/main/java/com/example/auction/bidding/api/BiddingService.java instead.

Comment: @ignasi35 Thanks. But how does the framework know how to recognize `:id`? What if you have multiple paths with different / multiple path parameters? Also it isn't clear to me why this validation happens here, and how the behaviour is defined when the condition (optional / required) fails.

Comment: `:id` is known to be a `UUID` because the method assigned to the call has an argument that is a `UUID`. In all cases, argument types are assigned to `:placeholder` in order. e.g. `ServiceCall<PlaceBid, BidResult> placeBid(UUID itemId); // used in pathCall("/api/item/:id/bids", this::placeBid)`